# xgboost performing poorly

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I'm rather new when it comes to using XGBoost but I thought it would be good to learn how to use it.

The dataset that I tried it on has 635 data points and 150 features. However the performance is rather poor around 50% when it comes to AUC. The same dataset when using logistic regression gives about 65%, after feature selection.

The parameters used are the standard ones that comes with the sklearn wrapper, XGBClassifier. I also tried to tune the parameters with GridSearchCV but the outcome became either the same or worse.

So my question:

Is the performance lacking because the dataset is to small or that there are to many features? Or maybe it's both?

Comment: Is your data balanced? Also you have quite a bit of variables in your data, given your sample size, you may want to reduce them first.

Comment: The outcome is binary and the outcome is distributed: 
0: 49 %
1: 51%

Comment: Are your variables numeric or categorical? What ratio?

Comment: all numeric, no missing values, and they are all scaled between 0 and 1. I tried to normalize the data but still same outcome

Comment: I would try reducing the number of variables, for ex. with CV, if scores still don't change, then your data may be poor for the given classification.

Comment: I'm thinking about doing that but I've read that forest based algorithms, such as xgboost, do implicit feature selection. But I'll try it and report back

Comment: It's true, but still the model will have an easier job of doing that with a smaller number of variables. The more variables you have the more likely you are to select a random variable which is a result of noise.